# Symfony2 Request extra query parameter missing

Tags: symfony, request

I need to use my route `site_edit` with an extra query parameter 'company'=1. The route is as follows:

```
@Route("/_sys/site/edit/{id}", name="site_edit", defaults={"id"=null})
```

Symfony2 generates the link `/_sys/site/edit?comp=1` which looks fine for me. It hits the action alright but Request#query is empty though $_GET is array('comp'=>'1').
If I adjust the query string to be `/_sys/site/edit/?comp=1` then no matching route is found. If I insert some value for {id} e.g. `/_sys/site/edit/new?comp=1` then all is fine ($id="new" and Request#query is array('comp'=>'1') but this case is not tolerable by application logic I must not change.

I need a route with very similar structure where exactly one of the parameters comp and id is present. So the urls need to be generated as [twig] `url('site_edit', {'id':positiveInteger})` or `url('site_edit', {'comp':positiveInteger})`.

Is this a bug? IMHO in `/_sys/site/edit?comp=1` the part before ? should launch the action with {id}=null (ok) and the part after ? should ensure that Request#query-get('comp') yields '1' (fail).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
@Route("/_sys/site/edit/{id}/comp/{comp}", name="site_edit", 
        defaults={"id"=null})
```

You can assign a default value to comp, to treat it as emtpy if you wish.

Comment: I think, in that case, you could not call `/_sys/site/edit//comp/1` (note the double `/`). At least I had that kind of problem when generating route for my `AJAX` request... (although I had both `defaults` and `requirements` route parameters)

Comment: id will default to null in this case

Comment: `/_sys/site/edit/1` would not hit the action. If this is symfony's weakness, I'd rather use $_GET directly than some dumb url like `/_sys/site/edit/1/comp` for workaround.

Comment: "//" often causes problems in the middle of URLs and, in my experience, should be avoided if possible. Could you create separate routes to cater for the variations and point them all to the same controller?